# C# Class library - Changing image build action to resource removes it from the project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a C# class library project, in which I would like to use some images as assets. However whenever I change the build action to "Resource" the file gets excluded from the project and I cannot include it again. Did I miss something or why does the file remain excluded.

Comment: What do you mean by excluded? Is it no visible in Solution viewer? You might want to include images better describing the issue.

Comment: I need to turn on all files in order to see my image again.

Where do I need to put into @Clemens?

Answer (score 0):

@DeJoon.

Base on my test, change the build action to "Resource" the image will get excluded from the project in C# class library (.Net Core/.Net 5).

In the C# class library (.Net Framework) change the build action to "Resource" the image is displayed correctly in the project.

You could try the following steps in the .Net Core class library.

1. Right-click the project and select Unload Project.
2. Right-click the project and select Edit Project File.
   Make sure your file is as follows：

[image]

3.After saving the file, right click on the project Reload Project, and then you can see the image.

Comment: Once I set `OutputType` and `UseWPF` the project cannot be compiled anymore. However I added the `<Resource Include="File" />`. But the build action is still None. Could the problem be that I use `net5.0` as `TargetFramework`?

Comment: Hi,@DeJoon. Well, I tested this method is useful for .Net Core but not for .NET5.

Comment: Well, I could just use embedded resource instead of resource and it worked out just fine. Thanks anyway :)